# renaming files with a (~) after the extension

Tags: regex, rename

I have about 3500 files (.doc  .xls  .pdf  etc.) they all have a "~" after the extension. ie blahblah.doc~ , blahblah.xls~  I am not familiar enough with regex to get the syntax correct. What would be the easiest command/script to do this in a bash shell.  thanks kindly.

Comment: Are we talking about files in the same folder? What OS, Linux?

Comment: if it is always finish with `~` use `(?:.+\..+~$)` ;).

Comment: I should have said, the end goal is to rename all the files without the trailing tilde (~)

Comment: If you're familiar with scripting in bash in general, but not specifically regex (which your question implies), what about general string manipulation - just substring with length - 1.

Comment: there are multiple folders , and yes the OS id linux (Debian)

Comment: James, do you have a simple example I could extrapolate from ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
rename -n 's/~$//' *.*
```

Obviously you will need to remove `-n` if you really want to make changes. Else it will show files that will be changed without touching them

Comment: rename -n 's/(.*)~$/$1/' *.*  does seem to work, it displays what I want. Which part do I remove so it writes it out ?

Comment: @BPatton You will need to remove `-n` .  I have simplified the regex a bit. Checkout the updated regex

Comment: argh, wouldn't "find . -iname *.*~ | rename  's/^(.*)~$/$1/' *.*  be able to go through the directory structure and change all the files ending with a ~!

Comment: It works within the directory when I run it,  (without using the find.......) Fortunately, there aren't that many directories and this is far to late for me being up. My associate is on holidays, thus I am left to figure it out. I appreciate your help. thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have subdirectories you can also use this python script:
What it does is checking if file has ~ and if it does it will delete the last char by with python's system so it will only work if you have just a ~ tilde in the last char. Alternatively you could use name.Endswith("~")

```
import os
from os.path import join

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path_to_parent_directory'):
    for name in files:
        #print (name) // for checking filenames
        if "~" in name: 
            os.rename(join(root,name),join(root,name[:-1]))
```

Comment: This will rename `ab~cd` with `ab~c`

Comment: this will rename abc~ with abc, as i did explain in the answer. You could use Endswith if you want to be more cautious